# c# - inheritence + reflection - how not to clone an object

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I found the following code snippet which puzzled me.

```
public class Bclass : Aclass
{
    public const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

    public Bclass(IAclass a) : base(string.Empty)
    {
        var destFields = this.GetType().BaseType.GetFields( Flags );

        a.GetType().GetFields( Flags ).Where(x => destFields.Contains(x)).ToList().ForEach(property =>
        {
            destFields.First(x => x == property).SetValue(this, property.GetValue(a));
        });

        var destProperties = this.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties( Flags );

        a.GetType().GetProperties( Flags ).Where(x => destProperties.Contains(x)).ToList().ForEach(property =>
        {
            destProperties.First(x => x == property).SetValue(this, property.GetValue(a, null));
        });
    }
    // some more methods... 
}
```

My main Q is.... why would anyone think of doing that...
What benefit(s) can come out of this code.

Comment: It looks like a *really, really* badly implemented meberwise clone from `a` into the new instance. It looks horrible, and is very inefficient

Comment: Protip: Use AutoMapper.

Comment: Why would anyone consider doing what? The fields copy? Or this terrible code in general? In my opinion reflection is typically a bad call in constructors. You ask about benefits, but versus what? Please clarify what you want out of this.

Comment: This code was written by a student - and we are debating about what his intesion was - i.e. why he did that, naturally, he thought it gains something - I think he was trying to extend a live object with more functionality. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it does: memberwise clone from `a` into the current newly created instance

Advantages:

- it stops your CPU from getting too cold by making sure it uses the maximum CPU cycles to do something simple
- it keeps the GC on its toes by doing a great amount of allocation in a simple object constructor without any of those crazy ideas like strategy caches
- it *kinda* reduces maintenance of having to write manual "copy the members" code, but: there are tools that do that very well and very efficiently that should be employed; or if that isn't an option, there are still *many ways of improving this code without making it insanely complex

Comment: And whould any private data of object 'a' be exposed to via an instantiation of B here?

Comment: @davidhadas because of `BindingFlags.NonPublic`, which tells the reflection API to peak behind the covers

Comment: But the since you are doing this on a base class..... you will not be getting access to the private data according to what I read. Otherwise a big nono for C#

Comment: @davidhadas that doesn't matter; when you use non-public reflection, regular rules of visibility are irrelevant

Comment: @davidhadas I should perhaps clarify that *whether you are allowed to do this* can depend on the platform/runtime you are using, and things like trust levels; but *in the general case* for regular .net on a full-trust setup: yes, you can look at and manipulate arbitrary data. Note that non-public reflection is often used (as a supported option) by library tools, and things like serialization libraries, ORM libraries, etc

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc(v=vs.110).aspx states: Specify BindingFlags.NonPublic to include non-public fields (that is, private, internal, and protected fields) in the search. Only protected and internal fields on base classes are returned; private fields on base classes are not returned.

Comment: @davidhadas ultimately, since `GetType()` is being used here, everything will be relative to *the concrete object* type, not the declared type; it is `a.GetType()`, not `typeof(IAclass)`. If `a` *actually is* a `Bclass`, then it is already the same type ;p Also: based on the code shown so far, I wouldn't rule out the possibility that all the fields are `public` !

Comment: this is really a non interesting edge case - assuming normal inheritence of a child class B inheriting a different parent class A , my understanding of the MSDN is that the child gets no access to the parent private parts - which means it is not exposed...

Comment: @davidhadas oh, it is still exposed - even if it doesn't come back from `parent.GetFields(...)`, you can just walk down the tree: `parent.BaseType.GetFields(...)` etc. Field accessibility is not a security feature: people can snoop.

Comment: ok, so I was making too much of this MSDN statement. I note though that using this code keeps private parts of Aclass to be private in Bclass - so again, this code seem to achieve nothing beyond a partial clone